# Why does this View display a dark background when set to Light Style?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-darkmode

My tableViews are working fine with Background = Default, but the rest of my views always display as Dark. What am I doing wrong? I am new to this...

[image: Xcode Screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

I think the default background color of a view transparent. Probably Xcode is just showing it as black when it's actually transparent.

If you want an actual, adaptive background color, use `System Background Color` instead (this will be white or black). If you need different shades, there are also the `Secondary` and `Tertiary` options.

Comment: I tried System Background Color and it previews in Xcode correctly, but at runtime it is always dark. Thanks for the suggestion. I am just going to hardcode those pages as light for now. I can't believe that I am the only one seeing this.

Comment: Something else must be amiss then. Those colors should definitely change dynamically. Are you only using storyboards or do you also do things in code?

Answer (score 0):

I would try hardcoding it in, like background = #fff(for hex0 or background = rgb(255,255,255). Sorry if it doesnt work, Im usually a flutter dev, not swift.

Comment: Hardcoding the color won't be useful if you want to support both light and dark mode. You should only post answers if you feel competent on the topic.

Comment: I didnt know they would like to support both modes, its not specified in the question.

Comment: Agree, I didn't say it, but yes, I want to support both - which is what Default is supposed to do. I suspect an xcode bug? How am I the only one? I have seached!